# Push Notification on virtual LAN

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

Does Push Notification depends on the kind of network device is running on? I do not get Push Notification on virtual LAN. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Is it only dependent on the virtual LAN, can you receive them when mobile data is turned on?

Comment: Hi Daniel, please see my comment below. Appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the VPN is blocking port 5223 as this is the port that the push notifications are sent to the device from the APNS servers. Other than that, if you can't test on any other network to make sure it's working, it could be anything from certificate issues, to not registering the device token correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are some exceptions to push notifications. For example:

*iPhones that are not connected to cellular data (or when the phone has low to no signal) MAY not receive push notifications when the display is off for a specific period since wifi is often automatically turned off to preserve battery.*

Were your display off for significant amount of time with no cellular network access?

Comment: My app does not run just on cellular network. It needs to be in specific network of my client which we get via connecting to VPN. We can simulate the environment via VLAN also but on VLAN we are not getting push notification.